# Visual Flow: Selecting a Record in a Flow Screen

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

It's been a while since I have dived into Salesforce's Flow product and before the Flow Lightning UI refresh rolled out.

I have done this in the Flash based UI so I am puzzled but what I am doing wrong now.

Use-case: A user is prompted to associate an existing record in Salesforce to another by creating a junction object.

Problem: I am getting stuck on the part after the user inputs a keyword which then drives a *contains* Lookup tool. The Lookup tool stores a *single* record to a variable-- however, how can I display this variable as a choice selection in a screen for the Flow end-user to decision on?

Answer (score 1):

The Get Records element in the new Flow Builder parallels the old Fast Lookup, and it comes with an option to support selecting more than one record to a Record Collection variable.

To configure that choice, double-click on the Get Records element to open its Edit screen. Then, find the section shown below:

[image: Flow Builder screenshot]

Select, as shown here, "All Records", and name an sObject collection variable, to store all of the records matching the query that you specify.

Comment: Thanks @david reed, I did get to this part and was able to store those records into an sObject collection variable. My challenge now is actually displaying those records back to the user in a subsequent Flow Screen as a series of choices they can select from